# Modifying angular objects at runtime from dev console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change some of the variables inside my angular modules from the console and keep hitting roadblocks.

I have a particular property that will eventually be provided by the backend server. Until that part is ready, I would like to test my templates by changing the property from the console.

So if I borrow an example from the angularjs doc:

```
myApp.value('clientId', 'a12345654321x');
myApp.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', 'clientId', function DemoController($scope, clientId) {
  $scope.clientId = clientId;
}]);
```

I would like to change the value at runtime from the console. Does anyone know of a way how?

I tried using a different global object but the digest is not picking up changes

```
var myNamespace = {clientId: "a12345654321x"};

myApp.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', function DemoController($scope) {
  $scope.specialGlobal = myNamespace;
}]);

//then in html template
<h1>{{specialGlobal.clientId}}</h1>
```

This works on initial load, but changes to `myNamespace.clientId` through the console are not propagated.

Runnuning angularjs 1.3.x

Comment: you can use text box for display and change of value, that what i do for testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current `scope` in the console via `angular.element` - target an ID that is within your controller:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector("#idOfElementInController")).scope();
```

Now you can change variables on the `$scope` via `scope`

```
scope.specialGlobal = "new value";
```

Comment: What he said... but note that you may also need to trigger an $apply() cycle for Angular to see your new value... Can't wait for ES6 Observers to fix this...

Comment: Perfect!! I did have to `scope.$apply()`

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you could use `$0` for the current selected element in the Element panel of DevTools.